# How to do summation by using for loop in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have this sum  ∑((4./pi)*(((-1).^n)/(2*n+1))*cos((2*n+1)*x)) for x=0 to 4*pi and n=0 to 24. I want to use for loop to calculate the sum of it .

Here is my code :

```
x=4*pi % it does not work when I put x=0:4*pi , matlab says : In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.
for n=0:length(x)
    f(i+1)= (4./pi).*(((-1).^n)./(2*n+1))*cos((2*n+1)*x);

end
xl=sum(f);
```

How can I fix that x become from 0 to 4*pi ?

Thanks

EDIT:

```
 x=0:4*pi;
    for n=0:13
        f(i+1)= (4./pi).*(((-1).^n)./(2*n+1))*cos((2*n+1)*x(n));

    end

    xl=sum(f);
```

Comment: Why do you want to use a loop here? We've told you before that there's a specific built-in function for this.

Comment: Do `x=0:4*pi`, but later inside the for loop refer to `x` as `x(n)`. Also, consider leaning some basic MATLAB, as this is a day1 problem.

Comment: I tried what you said before but did not work .. thanks

Comment: @Joe oh, but it *does* work. Learn some basic MATLAB, they have some good documentations there. People in Stackoverflow do not take positively someone posting very basic questions, as that is not the purpose of the webpage. Consider reading [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: @ Ander Biguri  look at my edit please ,, was that you mean ??,, thank you